# If $r$ is a primitive root of $m$, then $r$ is also a primitive root of each positive divisor $d$ of $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

> If $r$ is a primitive root of $m$, then $r$ is also a primitive root
>   of each positive divisor $d$ of $m$.

There is a proof of this statement [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~savitt/mathcamp/1999/primitive_roots.pdf) (see Theorem 4.4), but I cannot find this result in any of my number theory textbooks.  Does anyone know of a textbook that proves this result? Moreover, does anyone know the origin of this result?

Comment: A "special case" is sometimes proved, but hardly needs proving: that if $g$ is a primitive root of $p^{k+1}$ then $g$ is a primitive root of $p^k$. This takes care of things, because apart from $2$ and $4$, the numbers that have primitive roots are $p^k$ and $2p^k$. The result goes back at least to Gauss in *Disquisitiones*. Nowadays there is little interest in $p^k$, it is for $p$ that primitive roots are mainly useful.